# How to create a login to a Google Glass app?

Tags: authentication, google-glass

On https://glass.google.com/myglass, apps that require a login do it from the website before installing the app. How can I create an app that requires a login like this? I can't find anything in the documentation about it. Also, how can I test the app since it would not be in myglass?

Comment: Just to clarify - are you talking about Mirror API based Glassware, or a GDK based one?

Comment: Glassware GDK. For example, on https://glass.google.com/myglass, when I turn on Evernote, it launches a pop-up window that goes to https://www.evernote.com/Login.action... and I enter my Evernote login. Then when the app is installed on the device, somehow it's already logged in to Evernote with my account. The login is not done on the device.

Comment: That isn't really a good example since Evernote is using the Mirror API - not the GDK. Nothing gets installed to your device.

Comment: Evernote has a GDK app that lets you take notes that sync with your Evernote account. Or the same with Facebook app, install from myglass, pop-up login, app on device is logged into Facebook.

Comment: I'm not disputing that both the Evernote and Facebook Glassware let you authenticate when you turn them on through MyGlass and do stuff on Glass that sync with these services. But neither of them are GDK apps. Both of them are Mirror API based. There is a LOT you can do with the Mirror API without having to sideload anything onto Glass. The Mirror API is built on top of OAuth, which is incorporated already.

Comment: Examples of Glassware that require authentication but also have GDK components include Strava Cycling and Running and LynxFit.

Comment: Ok glass, take a note with... evernote... then voice input records note that syncs with my evernote account. That's not GDK? I thought mirror was just CNN news pushing stuff to the timeline.

Comment: Nope that's the Mirror API. You can setup a Contact to handle voice input commands. Couple of lines of code on the server to add and handle.

Comment: Interesting. I have to look into mirror if it can do that. I thought it was just pushed static content. I still need login to glass apps for most things I want to do though.

Comment: Mirror can certainly let you accept (some) voice commands and requires authentication to work - OAuth is part of the basic requirements. I don't know what else you are trying to do, however, and that may be a good topic for another StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Google has worked with some partners to get GDK-based Glassware in MyGlass that use auth, there is no public method to do so yet. This is a frequently requested feature, and you can expect that once the GDK leaves Developer Preview, it will be available.

Until then, you will need to test your app by sideloading the app onto Glass. If you're testing for yourself, you can hardcode the auth into the app, and many people have hacks that use QR codes.

Keep in mind that this only holds true for GDK Glassware. Anything built with the Mirror API has authentication as part of its web-based initialization which you can trigger without having to go through MyGlass.

Answer (score 1):

Currenlty, Google Glass apps implemented with GDK do not have access to authentication support. The Google Glass team has accepted this issue to be implemented, but it is not there in XE12. Information from the Glass Team indicates that such authentication will be through the Account Manager, when it does arrive.

Only speculation and rumors about when that will be! (Though I will look at XE14 carefully when it comes out, moving Glass Android to 4.2.2 (KitKat).)